# Multilayer LSTM without tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, lstm

To implement a multilayer LSTM network, I usually use the following code:

```
def lstm_cell():
    return tf.contrib.rnn.LayerNormBasicLSTMCell(model_settings['rnn_size'])
    
attn_cell = lstm_cell
    
def attn_cell():
    return tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm_cell(), output_keep_prob=0.7)
    
cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([attn_cell() for _ in range(num_layers)], state_is_tuple=True)
outputs_, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)
```

But, this way, I do not have access to the hidden layer outputs, if I want to manipulate the arrangements of the hidden layer outputs.
Is there any other way to make a multilayer LSTM network without using *tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply stack several LSTM layers, for example via the Sequential module:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.LSTM(..., return_sequences = True, input_shape = (...)))
model.add(layers.LSTM(..., return_sequences = True)
...
model.add(layers.LSTM(...))
```

In this case the `return sequences` keyword is crucial for the intermediate layers.